# How to get the correct pixel from a CGImage in a Retina Display device?

Tags: ios5, pixel, cgimage, retina-display

I have the following code which correctly retrieves the pixel color (RGB) being touched by the user's finger on an image based on the touch's current position (X and Y coordinate). So, this piece of code works fine but not for retina display devices:

```
-(void)drawFirstColorWithXCoord:(CGFloat)xCoor andWithYCoord:(CGFloat)yCoor
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage]; //image is an ivar of type UIImage
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    //GET PIXEL FROM POINT
    int index = 4*((width*round(yCoor))+round(xCoor));

    int R = rawData[index];
    int G = rawData[index+1];
    int B = rawData[index+2];

    NSLog(@"%d   %d   %d", R, G, B);

    free(rawData);
}
```

I would like to know what should I tweak in this code to make it work for retina display devices.

Any advice would be well apreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Stupid question: what's different about retina display devices? Why doesn't this code work - what do you get wrong?

Comment: Oh I see, well, retina display is a features in iPhone 4S and newer in which they doubled the resolution of the screen at least. In a normal iPhone you can only have an image of 320 x 480 MAX but in a retina display device the max would be 640 x 960 and they will fit well in the screen. So, in my code i'm not taking into consideration this calculation because for me one pixel equals one pixel that's why in normal devices i get the right pixel but in retina things scale up so the pixel that this code retrieves is not exactly the one being touched in the screen for those devices.

Comment: Right, sorry - I meant what's different about programming for retina devices. So you're saying iOS correctly scales the input back to the screen size you're assuming on iPhones and old iPads just not the new ones? That seems crazy.

Comment: ok, CGImageRef does not make the calculations of a retina display for a specific point in the screen, for that reason we have to do it manually but how?

Comment: did you find a solution? I am having same problems.
Nevermind, looks you just need to multiply your xCoord and yCoord by screen scale (2.0 for retina)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = width * scale * bytesPerPixel;
```

Comment: It should be UIImage's scale. The scale of the image may not be the same as the screen's default scale. Actually nor event the views on the screen. One can use 1x or even 0.5x scaled images or views on a 2x retina screen.